# Why is my wordpress website so slow and am I having so much downtime?

Tags: performance, wordpress, pagespeed, yslow, downtime

I have used Yslow and PageSpeed to find the cause, but I can't seem to figure out why my blog http://www.fotokringarnhem.nl sometimes loads blazing fast (cached files I guess), and other times takes about 10 seconds or longer to load.

I am on a shared server, but haven't had problems like this with other websites on shared servers.

I'm using cloudflare to speed up my blog to speed things up, but to no avail.

Am I missing something?

Pingdom reports of last 30 days (also see http://stats.pingdom.com/hseaskprwiaz):

- Response time average: 7.620 ms
- Slowest Average: 18.307 ms
- Fastest Average: 4.237 ms
- Uptime: 96,24%

**Edit 1**: 
from basicstate.com

diagnostics

+dns 
+connect 
-request 
-response

So I guess it fails on the requests. Options to narrower it down?

**Edit 2**:

I used [P3 (Plugin Performance Profiler)](http://support.godaddy.com/godaddy/wordpress-p3-plugin/) to determine which plugins caused the most loadtime. Turns out that User Access Manager caused about 60% of load time, so I deleted it.

This did something, I now get way less time outs, but it still takes a long time for anything to popup on the screen.

I used the plugin [SQL monitor](http://blog.sjinks.pro/wordpress-plugins/sqlmon/) and determined there are 82 queries being executed on request which takes about 10 seconds!!!!

Comment: pingdom seems to be saying that your average response time over the last 7 days was about 11 ms. That doesn't seem like a bad average to me. But Sep 5, down for 9 hours? If you're seeing more variation than pingdom reports--and you're not changing your blog's code every day--consider trying a different service that gives more detail.  [basicstate.com](http://basicstate.com/htm/show.htm) is one I've used in the past.

Comment: Thank you, I have added my website there. Will post results later.

Comment: Added results from basicstate.com

Comment: Added new insight into SQL queries, but how to tackle this problem. Seems to me wordpress needs these queries. Would changing hosts solve the problem?

Comment: 88 queries for *each* page request?

Comment: certainly for the homepage, if you turn on your console in firebug or something similar and you open the page, console.log the amount of queries and time this took, I stand corrected, it is 82 for the homepage: 82 database queries in 9.850 seconds, using 44.12MB memory

Comment: I can't help going back to your pingdom.com history. If you had 99% up time, you'd expect to be down for 15 minutes a day. Now look at your history. In September, you're showing about 140 outages of more than 10 minutes, and it's only Sept 13. With that kind of server performance, I'm not sure *any* other measurements are meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the P3 plugin
and use this article to further optimize your website: http://andbreak.com/articles/guide-speed-wordpress/

when all else fails, try switching providers

**Edit**

Turns out that deleting all automatically saved backups of pages and post as well as the concepts was the key. This dramatically cuts my query time to the server.
Now at lightning speeds!
Here is the report from the last few days:
uptime: 99,21%
overall average: 3.322 ms

There is a usefull plugin for WP to also limit the number of autosaves and concepts for posts and pages: [Revision control](http://dd32.id.au/wordpress-plugins/revision-control/)
Results weren't instant by the way. Took a day to take effect.

Basicstate results (clearly showing the improvement when I deleted the revisions and concepts on the 11th of 12th (not sure which)).

```
date          uptime       dns   connect   request      ttfb      ttlb
2012-09-18     98.97     0.031     0.047     0.047     0.353     0.475
2012-09-17    100.00     0.031     0.047     0.047     0.389     0.810
2012-09-16    100.00     0.029     0.045     0.045     0.342     0.499
2012-09-15     93.81     0.029     0.045     0.045     0.739     1.035
2012-09-14     98.97     0.053     0.068     0.068     0.387     0.565
2012-09-13    100.00     0.058     0.074     0.074     0.499     0.853
2012-09-12     95.00     0.030     0.046     0.046     5.994     7.024
2012-09-11     96.97     0.051     0.096     0.096     9.707     9.949
2012-09-10     73.15     0.027     0.043     0.043     6.765     6.952
2012-09-09     43.48     0.027     0.121     0.121     3.652     3.724
2012-09-08     31.82     0.028     0.045     0.045     2.757     2.867
2012-09-07     71.93     0.026     0.042     0.042     5.917     6.091
2012-09-06     60.49     0.027     0.043     0.043     4.590     4.751
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a static site with not millions of users and performance is highly variable, your host is probably to blame. I have tried about 8 different hosts and researched a dozen others, I highly suggest Media Temple (mt). Best customer service and performance you can get for the money.

Also, check out a speed test tool by WP Engine: http://speed.wpengine.com/ - great insight into why your site is slow. Takes a few hours to generate a report.

Comment: I second this answer. From my past experiences the lag in a situation like this is almost always the hosts fault. Unless you have some processes getting stuck, bad plugin etc.

Comment: I have other websites (although not wordpress) with this host and haven't had such problems, I just thought I can make a copy of the site and set up a localhost using xamp to test it. Would this help me? I have tried the link you placed, but am not sure they'll be able to help with an automated script.

Comment: @DaniëlTulp what do you mean an automated script? It runs and points out where there are speed issues on your site, if any. And there could be many issues with the host, perhaps that cluster is slow, or their systems aren't optimized for wordpress.

Comment: I e-mailed my provider today about the issue. Hope they can come up with a solution. @antonpug I meant that I expected to get further with real life people like yourself than with a script that analyses my website. I was correct, the script couldn't find anything and now I get e-mails from them offering their services.