# My wordpress website and dashboard ,both are too slow, server responded in 11 sec

Tags: performance, wordpress, server, pagespeed

Domain of my blog is [codesaviour](http://www.codesaviour.com).
Since last month my blog and wp-admin dashboard has slowed down to a frustrating level. I have already removed post revision after reading from [speeding up wordpress](http://andbreak.com/articles/guide-speed-wordpress/).
Here is the [Google PageSpeed Insight](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codesaviour.com&tab=desktop) report of my blog. According to it **server responding time is 11s**.

I even read following threads in stack overflow :
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289023/why-is-my-wordpress-website-so-slow-and-am-i-having-so-much-downtime). I tried to implement the steps but blog is still slow,no change.

My host is Hostgator.in,their online assistance asked me to enable gzip compression as instructed at [link](http://gtmetrix.com/enable-gzip-compression.html),So I followed the instruction, as I was not having .htaccess file on server I created one and pasted the code mentioned in previous link,but nothing helped. It is slow like before, even online reports doesn't show that gzip is even working.

Here is a [report](http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.codesaviour.com/wM2l9cpV) from gtmetrix that includes Pagespeed and YSlow reports.Third Tab `Timeline` shows that it took 11.46s in receiving.

**Main problem is server response of 11s (*google pagespeed report*) or 11.46s(*gtmetrix report*).**
 Google suggests to reduce it under 200ms ,How can I reduce it?

@Constantine responded in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078327/wordpress-website-loading-too-slow) , that many wordpress website are going through same slow phase.

I am using following plugins:

- Akismet
- Google Analyticator
- Google XML Sitemaps
- Jetpack by WordPress.com
- Revision Control
- SyntaxHighlighter Evolved
- WordPress Gzip Compression
- WordPress SEO
- WP Edit

Every time I select add new plugin following error is reported,

> An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with
>   WordPress.org or this server’s configuration.

Also whenever i am installing any plugin using upload option, its giving me error :

> Can't load versions file.
>
> http_request_failed

Please help me,in order to **increase speed** of my blog and dashboard, also suggestion for the errors I am receiving.

**Edit**

Automatically , without any changes , 11.46s has been reduced to 1.26s .

Answer (score 0):

I will focus on the speed issue. Generally, when things start to be slow, it is a good idea to test by gradually switching off the features until it is fast. The last thing you switched off before it is fast is slow. Then look at that thing in details. Try to split the given task to subtask and do it again, until you find the exact cause of the problem. I would do that with the plugins as well. After the testing is finished, I would put the features back.

Answer (score 0):

Use an effective caching plugin like "WP Super Cache". It drastically improves your page"s load time. Optimizing your images is also essential for your site"s speed. WP-SmushIt performs great for this issue.The last plugin which I highly recommend you is WP-Optimize.This plugin basically clean up your WordPress database and optimize it without doing manual queries. It sometimes gives error when you installed the same plugin more than ones. Firstly, you should delete the plugin from your ftp program instead of using wordpress platform. Otherwise, its not working properly due to errors. Then try to install again the same plugin which you had already deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to maintain a site about programming then you really have to fix the performance. It really is awful.

The advice you get from automated tools isn't always that good.

Looking at the link you provided the biggest problem is the HTML content generation from GET http://codesaviour.com/ which is taking 11.46 seconds (there are problems elsewhere - but that is by far the worst) - 99% of the time the browser is just waiting - it only takes a fraction of a second to transfer the content across the network. Wordpress is notorious for poor performance - often due to overloading pages with plugins. Your landing page should be fast and cacheable (this fails on both counts).

> even online reports doesn't show that gzip is even working

The HAR file you linked to says it **is** working. But compression isn't going to make much impact - it's only 8.4Kb uncompressed. The problem is with the content generation.

You should certainly use a Wordpress serverside cache module ([here's a good comparison](http://cd34.com/blog/scalability/wordpress-cache-plugin-benchmarks/)).

DO NOT USE the Wordpress Gzip plugin - do the compression on the webserver - it's much faster and more flexible.

In an ideal world you should be using ESI - but you really need control over the infrastructure to implement that properly.

Diagnosing performance problems is hard - fixing them is harder and that is when you have full access to the system it's running on. I would recommend you set up a local installation of your stack and see how it performs there - hopefully you can reproduce the behaviour and will be able to isolate the cause - start by running HPROF, checking the MySQL query log (I'm guessing these aren't available from your hosting company). You will howevver be able to check the state of your opcode cache - there are free tools for both APC and ZOP+. Also check the health of your MySQL query cache.

Other things to try are to disable each of the plugins in turn and measure the impact (you can get waterfalls in Firefox using the Firebug extension, and in chrome using the bundled developer tools).

You might also want to read up a bit on performance optimization - note that most books tend to focus on the problems client-side but your problems are on your server. You might even consider switching to a provider who specializes in Wordpress or use a different CMS.

Comment: Hi @syncbean ,thanks for your response.
I don't know how , but today my website server-reponse has been reduced automatically from 11.46s to 1.26s . I didn't even changed anything yet.After reading all responses I was going to implement each and suggestion.Can you come up with any reason , what would have happened ?

Comment: I am worried if everything become slow again

Comment: Or a failed DNS/Ident lookup (whcih would be very sloppy on the part of your service provider)

Answer (score 0):

symcbean's answer is good, but I would add a few things:

#### This is a server-side issue

This has been said by others, but I want to further emphasize that this is a server side issue, so all those client-side speed testing tools are going to be of very limited value

#### HostGator isn't high-performance hosting

I don't know about India, but HostGator in the US is generally very slow for dynamic, database driven sites (like yours).  It absolutely shouldn't take 11 seconds to load the page, especially since your site doesn't look particular complex, but unless you're serving a totally static site, HostGator probably won't ever give you really stellar performance.

#### Shared hosting leaves you at the mercy of badly-behaved "neighbors"

If you're using one of HostGator's standard shared hosting packages (I'm assuming you are), you could have another site on the same machine using too many resources and crippling the performance of your site.  See if you can get HostGator to look into that.

#### Why not use a service built for this?

This looks like a totally standard blog, so a service like Tumblr or Wordpress.com (not .org) might be a better choice for your needs.  Performance will be excellent and the cost should be very low, even with a custom domain name. If you aren't experienced in managing WordPress and don't have any interest in learning how (don't blame you), why not leave all that to the experts?

Comment: Hi @Chris ,thanks for your response.
I don't know how , but today my website server-reponse has been reduced automatically from 11.46s to 1.26s . I didn't even changed anything yet.After reading all responses I was going to implement each and suggestion.Can you come up with any reason , what would have happened ?

Comment: i am worried , if everything become slow again. :(

Comment: I'd guess that another site on the same server was slowing things down.  There's not much you can do about that - it's the risk you run using cheap shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some adjustment to improve your speed up WordPress.
The first step is: clean some unwanted plugins you had in WordPress.
The second step is: delete the theme you not used.
The third step is: compress all images with lossless quality.
The fourth step is: Clean up the database.
If you have done all these steps you will fix your WordPress. You want more details to check out this link: [How to fix WordPress dashboard slow](https://tutreal.com/wordpress-dashboard-slow/).

Answer (score 0):

Other than the usual suggestions, if you are hosting your MySql db on another host from the web server, check the latency between the two. Wordpress is unbelievably chatty with it's db (50+ db calls to load each dashboard page, for example). By moving the db onto the same host as the web server, I got excellent performance.